# How to tell VLC which subtitle language file to display by default?

Tags: vlc-media-player, subtitles

I am using VLC 1.1.11

[image]

I have a movie with two subtitles, both UTF, one is movie.en.srt and other in movie.he.srt (Hebrew if you ask)

When I play the file: movie.avi, both subs: movie.en.srt and movie.he.srt load, and the default one that is shown is movie.en.srt

-track 1 and track 2
[image]

I would like to set that the he srt file will be displayed by default.

I tried to set the settings for the language but that's not helping.
[image]

-- The solution can be either of 2:

1. Have VLC play Track 2 by default
2. Have VLC load the order of the SRT files in my preferred order.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think VLC sorts the .srt files in alphabetical order. try to rename your files to  movie.A.he.srt  and movie.B.en.srt